# T-SQL вопрос по конструированию скрипта

Tags: sql-server

**Добрый день.**

Столкнулся с во таким вопросом: есть сущность и есть состояния это сущности. Т.е.
таблица А - список объектов, а таблица Б - список состояний этих объектов. Допустим, для каждого объекта А есть по 2 состояния в таблице Б. В сложных запросах в выборках, когда объединяются эти две таблицы (и другие), у нас получается по 2 записи для объекта А, но с разными состояниями.

Грубо говоря, как указать указать студии, что я хочу брать последнее состояние объекта при джоине?

Спасибо.

Кусок кода:

```
SELECT 
        B.[bulkId],
        [loadTime],
        [startTime],
        [fileName],
        [User],
        [fileContent],
        C.clientName,
        LBS.[bulkStatusText] as [Status],
        C.clientId
    FROM
        [dbo].[Bulks] B 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[BulkStatuses]      BS ON  B.bulkId = BS.bulkId 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ListBulkStatuses] LBS ON  BS.[bulkStatusId] = LBS.[bulkStatusId]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Clients] C            ON  B.[clientId] = C.clientId
    WHERE 
        ([loadTime] BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd)
        AND
        ((@User IS NULL) OR (@User = [User]))
        AND
        ((@filename IS NULL) OR (@filename = [fileName]))       
        AND
        ((@showDeletedBulks IS NULL) OR ( LBS.bulkStatusId <> 5))
        AND
        ((@bulkStatus IS NULL) OR ( LBS.bulkStatusText = @bulkStatus))
        AND
        (@statusId IS NULL ) OR @statusId = LBS.[bulkStatusId]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример того как можно это реализовать.
Таблица объектов:

`declare @objects table (id int, name nvarchar(255))`

Таблица состояний:

`declare @conditions table (id int, objectId int, condition int)`

В таблицах поле id автоинкрементное поле, которое будет нам гарантировать уникальность. Заполняем таблицы:

```
insert into @objects
select 1, 'a' union all
select 2, 'b' union all
select 3, 'c' 


insert into @conditions
select 1, 1, 1 union all
select 2, 1, 2 union all
select 3, 2, 1 union all
select 4, 2, 2 union all
select 5, 3, 1 union all
select 6, 3, 2 union all
select 7, 3, 3
```

Для третьего объекта делаем 3 состояния - для наглядности. Получаем все id таблицы состояний с последним состоянием (считаем что чем больше id в таблице состояний, тем состояние более последнее):

```
select c.id
from @conditions c
where id in (select max(id) from @conditions c_ group by c_.objectId)
```

Далее можно уже делать `join` с таблицей объектов и брать нужные данные.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!